# Background Color Map with D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

There is a way to set the background colour of a map depending on the projection that I want to use? Not for all the SVG "space" but only on the limits of the projection

If it's not clear for now I obtain this by setting a rect that occupy all SVG and using it as a background:
[image]

But I want to obtain something like this:
[image]

Where also the background of the globe is different, depending on the projection I use